# Can I change the Azure Work place Join Device status to compliance using Graph APis and ADAL library

Tags: azure, adal

I am trying to use the below API.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/intune_deviceconfig_devicecompliancedevicestatus_update

Can you please explain about the path variables using in this API?
deviceCompliancePolicyId
deviceComplianceDeviceStatusId.

Here is my sample code

```
  private static String patchComplianceCheckh(String accessToken) throws IOException {


  String s1 =  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/deviceCompliancePolicies/71889b5c-8ea2-473c-9a95-23bcd0e15ae8/deviceStatuses/2fa7d8fe-f410-4872-9991-87092a6ac070";

    URL url = new URL(s1);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestProperty("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "PATCH");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
 //   conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type","application/json");
    int httpResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("httpResponseCode " + httpResponseCode);
    if(httpResponseCode == 200) {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        StringBuilder response;
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            response = new StringBuilder();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
        System.out.println(response.toString());
        return response.toString();
    } else {
        return String.format("Connection returned HTTP code: %s with message: %s",
                httpResponseCode, conn.getResponseMessage());
    }
}
```

How do I send the request params to the request? I am getting 411 HTTP error code.

Comment: `The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 411 Length Required client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request without a defined Content-Length header.` But according to your code, it seems that there is no request body.

Answer (score 0):

**DeviceCompliancePolicyId**

Do below call -

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/deviceCompliancePolicies
```

The ID ("id": "4214b716-b716-4214-16b7-144216b71442") returned in below Response is the DeviceCompliancePolicyId-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 393

{
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.deviceCompliancePolicy",
      "id": "4214b716-b716-4214-16b7-144216b71442",
      "createdDateTime": "2017-01-01T00:02:43.5775965-08:00",
      "description": "Description value",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-01-01T00:00:35.1329464-08:00",
      "displayName": "Display Name value",
      "version": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

**DeviceComplianceDeviceStatusId**

Do below call -

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/deviceCompliancePolicies/{deviceCompliancePolicyId}/deviceStatuses
```

The ID ("id": "c6c78124-8124-c6c7-2481-c7c62481c7c6") returned in below Response is the DeviceComplianceDeviceStatusId-

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 544

{
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.deviceComplianceDeviceStatus",
      "id": "c6c78124-8124-c6c7-2481-c7c62481c7c6",
      "deviceDisplayName": "Device Display Name value",
      "userName": "User Name value",
      "deviceModel": "Device Model value",
      "complianceGracePeriodExpirationDateTime": "2016-12-31T23:56:44.951111-08:00",
      "status": "notApplicable",
      "lastReportedDateTime": "2017-01-01T00:00:17.7769392-08:00",
      "userPrincipalName": "User Principal Name value"
    }
  ]
}
```